# How to run podman and buildah without writing to home directory?

Tags: podman, buildah

There is almost no disk space left in my home directory but
I have a lot of disk space in the directory */scratch/tmpexperiment*. That directory is now empty.

I would like to try out the commands `podman` and `buildah` (just to  experiment and learn). After the experiment I would like to erase the directory */scratch/tmpexperiment*.

Is it possible to instruct `podman` and `buildah` to only create and write files under  */scratch/tmpexperiment*?

Preferably my home directory should remain untouched during the experiment (or at least modified as little as possible).

My user does not have sudo permissions. This question is regarding non-root (rootless) use of podman and buildah. The installed software versions are podman 1.4.0 and 1.9.0-dev.

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe setting some environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this.  One would be to bind mount a directory fro /stratch/tmpexperiment on ~/.local/share/containers.

Second would be to run

podman info, 
then edit ~/.config/containers/storage.conf

And modify graphroot option

graphroot = "/home/dwalsh/.local/share/containers/storage"

To something like

graphroot = /stratch/tmpexperiment/containers/storage

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04: `mount -o bind /stratch/tmpexperiment  ~/.local/share/containers` fails with  _mount: only root can use "--options" option_ .  My user does not have sudo permissions. But it looks like the second way will work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the possibilities outlined by @rhatdan, the Podman [documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman.1.html) offers up another option:

> In Rootless mode images are pulled under XDG_DATA_HOME when specified, otherwise in the home directory of the user under $HOME/.local/share/containers/storage.

So in your case e.g.

```bash
env XDG_DATA_HOME=/stratch/tmpexperiment/containers/storage podman run <container>
```

should work.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686244/3465171).